# Android.Support.V4 is not referenced error

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am having problems implementing a MvxTabsFragmentActivity, very similar to the one Stuart created in one of his [examples](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Fragments/FragmentSample.UI.Droid/Views/TabView.cs).

I am getting this error:

> The type 'Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity' is defined in an assembly that is  not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Problem is, I have referenced Mono.Android.Support.v4 and it appears to be correctly referenced:

[image: References]

There is a difference between the versions required and the version actually referenced, could the error be coming from there?

[image: Mono Android support version]

Does anyone know how to solve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You will need to install [component](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamandroidsupportv4-18) from the store. It's not the same as Mono.Android.Support.v4.